# Modify X axis labels in plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-mining

I have this dataset:

```
day1 = df[df.day==2]
day1 = day1[['date','CO2',"hour"]]
```

[image]

With this code:

```
ts1 = day1.CO2
plt.plot(ts1)
plt.show()
```

I obtain:

[image]

How can i modify X-axis with the hours?

Comment: Try `day1.plot(x='date', y='CO2')`, remember to convert `date` into `datetime` type.

Comment: It work's but i have all the date in the x-axis and i can't read because they overlap, so i want only the hours, but the order of the date

Comment: Review my previous comment **remember to convert date into datetime**

Comment: Yes but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I think you need to put `day1.plot(x='hour', y='CO2')`.